# CSS to get a div stuck to the bottom of a bootstrap column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a template that has three columns - two are lists and the third is going to be data. I'm trying to format the first two lists to be scrollable and then have the bottom of the list column to be a button. I would like the button to be fixed at the bottom always.

I assume that I have to add some sort of fixed height for the list-group and then set overflow-y: scroll to get the scroll look but how can i set the div at the bottom of the list to always be at the bottom of the page?

I've also included a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/3W6aFI1nngtMbWzYnUVC

Thanks for the help

For instance, this is what one column would look like:

```
   <div class="col-sm-3">
  <!-- this div to be a scrollable list -->
  <div class="list-group contact">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">Items</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">Items</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">Items</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">Items</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">Items</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">Items</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">Items</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">Items</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">Items</a>
  </div>
  <!-- This div to be stuck at the bottom -->
  <div>
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-default">New</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is, add a fixed height to the Divs you want to be scrollable and allow [scrollbars](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) on the div.

Modify your CSS to include the below snippet or add them in-line to your Divs:

```
height:100px; overflow:scroll;
```

Working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/aDICWE7NJhnVIVFfIebv)

Comment: OK that is originally what I assumed and tried as well. But if I add ``` height: 800px ``` then the window scroll bar still scrolls past the buttons. How would I get it so that the button div at the bottom is fixed to the bottom of the window within the column and then the list takes up the rest of the column length? maybe thats a better explanation of my issue

Comment: Are you adding the Style to Div with `col-sm-3` class on it ([like this](http://plnkr.co/edit/aDICWE7NJhnVIVFfIebv)) ? If so, it should rather be added to the Div containing your List.

Comment: Yes sorry I shouldve specified. I was adding it to the Div containing the List like your example. However, if the mouse is not on the list and on any part of the page - it can scroll. How can I get the div with the button to stick to the bottom of the window? I've tried setting the height of the list equal to the height of the body and that didnt work either. Any other thoughts are appreciated